# Как создать массив с ограниченным размером Swift 3?

Tags: массивы, ios, swift3

Мне надо создать массив с ограниченным размером, 11 цифр типа `Integer`.
Пробовал так, но тут создается массив из нулей, а мне нужен пустой массив с ограниченным размеров состоящих из 11 цифр типа `Integer`.

```
var temp = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 11)
```

Comment: Тебе нужен именно `[Int]`? Нельзя использовать `[Int?]`?

Comment: так что не так с тем, что у вас в вопросе? забейте нулями и потом меняйте на нужные вам цифры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через массив опциональных `Int`:

```
var temp = [Int?](repeating: nil, count: 11)
```